# How use sql "like" in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

How use sql "like" in PyMongo?

```
>>> db.houses.find().count()
11616
>>> db.houses.find({"hid":u"16999"}).count()
1
>>> db.houses.find({"hid":u"/9/"}).count()
0
```

The [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) says that sql "like" (`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE "%Joe%"`) in MongoDB is `db.users.find ({name:/Joe/})`.

If you specify a query directly to the cli-client interface mongodb, then everything works correctly, but does not work in pymongo.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

pymongo doesn't support regex literals, you have to use the '$regex' predicate:

```
 db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": u"9"}})
```

Comment: what is the syntax if 9 represented as variable(search_word)?    
db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": usearch_word}}) .... ???

Comment: @vogash: I guess, yes. Note that mongodb uses PCRE regexes, not python's.

Comment: it says that variable usearch_word is not defined

Comment: Any answer, can you send example of using parameter instead of hard coded 9

Comment: Worked for me in python 3.7. Thanks a lot.