# How to query MongoDB ObjectId by last 6 characters

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo and tried to use regex where I concatenate the alphanumeric 18 character string regex expression + a variable containing the last 5 exact characters of the ObjectId. How would I go about finding the node with `ObjectId: 5a7fb66cbf10c7c8c3f0aea0` using `f0aea0`?
Would this require saving a duplicate ObjectId of type string?

This was my attempt:

```
    sell = db.sells
    idNumber = "5a7fb66cbf10c7c8c3f"+str(array[1])
    regexstr = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]{18}"+"265d51"
    regex = re.compile(regexstr, re.IGNORECASE)
    sale = sell.find_one({"_id" : regex})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use sql "like" in PyMongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018730/how-use-sql-like-in-pymongo)

Comment: My main issue here is the incompatibility with ObjectId with String when using regex.

Comment: I've never done this with `ObjectId` but I'd give it a shot with aggregations and `$strLenBytes`. If that wouldn't work I'd firstly project ObjectId to a string and then match it with `$strLenBytes`.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't think of a better solution than to add a field with the string version of it