# PyMongo - Using variables to sql 'LIKE' queries

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, filter, pymongo

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018818/4636715) applies when using PyMongo to search fields containing a search text. But only for hard-coded string values:

```
 db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": u"9"}})
```

So, how to shape that expression replacing that `"9"` with a variable?

```
def some_func(search_text)
    db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": ??????}})
```

Comment: are you stating that `db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": search_text}})` won't work?

Comment: The linked answer had comments looking for that kind of implementation. So, this question is for the ones hitting the end of the road on that question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
search_text = u"9"
db.houses.find({"hid":{"$regex": search_text }})
```

Comment: Ok, my first example confused you. Putting `search_text` that way is not always possible.

Comment: @vahdet From comments provided from linked answer. it's `'9'` where `u'9'` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re` module to create a regex for your search string

```
import re
search_string = re.compile('9')
db.houses.find({'hid': search_string})
```

you can use a lot of options available in `re` module